# link project folder to dropbox folder using linux

Tags: linux, dropbox

I want to share the project with others to develop faster so I decided to link the project directory to the Dropbox using Linux but when I create a link folder from Dropbox to my project it's not working and I can't import libraries.

**how can I link a folder from Dropbox into my project folder and import libraries?**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course its better for you to use git instead, but you can do it by some simple command named `rsync`.

`rsync` can use for remote sync or local sync.

```
 
case "$1" in
    start)
        process_id=`ps -aux | grep "synchronize_script" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}' | awk 'END{ print NR }'`;
        tolerable=3;
        if [ $process_id -ge $tolerable ]
        then
            echo "synchronize_script already started !!!";
        else
            while true; do
                sleep 3;
        rsync -az --delete /PathToProjectSource/SpecificFolder1/  /PathToProjectDestination/TheSameSpecificFolder1/;
            # YOU CAN ADD SpecificFolders AS MANY AS YOU WANT BY ADDING ANOTHER LINE LIKE ABOVE INTO WHILE LOOP.
            done &
            echo "started"
        fi
        ;;
    stop)
        process_id=`ps -aux | grep "synchronize_script" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}' | awk 'END{ print NR }'`;
        tolerable=2;
        if [ $process_id -eq $tolerable ]
        then
            echo "no synchronize_script started yet";
        else
            kill -9 `ps -aux | grep "synchronize_script" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 { start | stop }"
esac
```

here is the link of my script using `rsync` and `dropbox`.

[github/mahdifox](https://github.com/mahdifox/My-Repository/blob/master/synchronize_script.sh)